# Функция выполняющаяся через определенный промежуток времени

Tags: c++, функции, время

Нужно сделать функцию которая будет выполняться ровно каждые 0.002 секунды или каждую мс. Как это можно сделать чтобы при этом работало на всех платформах?

Comment: Как мне кажется, такая высокая точность требует операционную систему реального времени...

Comment: @Harry Я планирую использовать Linux Windows и Mac

Comment: Никак. Точность выхода потока из спячки в винде приметно 1 мс. У линукса примерно также.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков а если тогда каждую мс?

Comment: Как вариант, можно создать отдельный поток, который в цикле будет отсчитывать высокоточное время и ровно через заданные промежутки вызывать искомую функцию. Под Windows для этого существуют функции QueryPerformanceFrequency() и QueryPerformanceCounter(), под Linux и Mac должно существовать аналогичное API (мануалы в помощь). Чтобы работало на всех платформах, без директив условной компиляции скорее всего не обойтись.

Comment: А вы поэкспериментируйте, скажем, с setitimer (в *nix). Вполне возможно, что  требуемая вам точность будет обеспечена, особенно если запускать от рута и повысить приоритет процесса до realtime. Только, чтобы ошибка не накапливалась, надо делать single-shot timer и считать каждый следующий интервал вручную

Comment: Серавно не пройдёт. Да и ненужна такая точность, и такие частовыэываемые функции в простом приложении.

Comment: Я думаю, что решения универсального нет. Вопрос: а что конкретно вы хотите выполнять 500-1000 раз в секунду? Какие операции?

Comment: главное, что бы не выяснилось, что это управление каким-нибудь рентгеновским прибором или контроль запуска ракеты. И чуть винда решила диском пошуршать и готово....

Answer (score 2):

Ну, можно попробовать что-то вроде

```
void func0002()
{
    m.lock();
    ++counter;
    cout << counter << "\r";
    m.unlock();
}

int main()
{
    auto sx = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(;;)
    {
        this_thread::sleep_until(sx+=2ms);
        thread t(func0002);
        t.detach();
    }
}
```

но гарантии точности все равно никто не даст...

Ну, или если программа больше ничего не должна делать -

```
int counter;

void func0002()
{
    ++counter;
    cout << counter << "\r";
}

int main()
{
    auto sx = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(;;)
    {
        this_thread::sleep_until(sx+=2ms);
        func0002();
    }
}
```

Comment: функция main получается просто выполняется каждые 2мс? Или я что-то не понимаю.

Comment: Хм, в однопоточном варианте между двумя последовательными вызовами `func0002`  обязательно есть вызов `sleep_until`, но в многопоточном же варианте совсем не обязательно. Главный поток может успеть создать штук 100 новых потоков, которые одновременно попытаются захватить мьютекс. Как только один из потоков освободит мьютекс, какой-нибудь другой тут же без всяких `sleep`'ов захватит его...

Comment: @wololo Да многопоточный вариант вообще ничего не должен лочить, это я перемудрил. Если нужна синхронизация вызовов (функция не успевает за 0.002 выполниться) - дело вообще-то плохо - надо, чтоб ядер хватало etc etc...